# Scroll by moving the mouse to the edges of the screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, hotkeys, scrolling, user-experience

Is there a way to scroll by moving the mouse to the edges of the screen?

For example trigger a scroll down when I move the mouse to bottom of the screen when the browser is focused?

This is basically like RTS games' camera behavior.

Comment: AHK code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32039627/4279201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to do a little bit of programming, you can set up an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script that can trigger the down arrow on your keyboard continuously if you move your cursor to the bottom of the window, which would create the desired effect. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027784/trigger-ahk-script-based-on-the-position-of-the-mouse/32028293) for more information, user [ahkcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914172/ahkcoder) may be able to provide you with the exact script you need.

Alternatively, most browsers allow you to scroll by holding the middle-mouse and dragging down in addition to normal scrolling methods.